# Bounds of the integral for the area of a sphere cut out of a cylinder.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the surface area cut out of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=a^2$ such that $0\le a \le 1$.

How do I find the bounds of the integral? Is it $0\le\theta\le2\pi$ and $0\le r\le a$ in polar coordinates?